# Convert a downloaded image to in-memory static image -IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

My scenario goes in this way. At the start of application a list of images will be downloaded from server & once downloaded all images will be converted into the static images and onwards will be using those static images everywhere in application. I think in android this thing can be achieved using BITMAP. (Not confirm).

Currently i'm using [SDWEBIMAGE](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library for downloading and caching images. But i don't want to use this library anymore. I just want to download all images once and then everywhere i want to add below code snippet for displaying downloaded images.

```
[ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadedImageName"]];
```

Is there any way to get this thing done in ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download each Image and save it into "Documents" Directory, and then whenever you need them use that.

For saving image into documents directory, use code like this:

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(UIImage*)img {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
}
```

And for getting and show image on imageview, use this code:

```
- (UIImage*)getImage 
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` method is only for getting images that already exist in your app bundle. So if you have dynamic content that is downloaded from internet, you cannot use this method. Rather, create your own method to load the images from sandbox Documents folder.